# Why do electrons pass the cross in a Crookes tube?

Tags: electricity

In a Crookes tube there is a cathode and a cross shaped anode.

The anode attracts the electrons so why do some electrons pass the anode to strike the screen behind.

It's not as if the cathode is shooting electrons out like a gun, they are following field lines from the cathode to the anode.

Also the electrons that do pass the anode should bend towards the anode somewhat and hence there should not be a clear image on the screen. Would some of the electrons bend such that they strike the centre of the shadow area and everywhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of for now is that they gain a very large velocity that they can not bend that much in the much shorter distance behind the cross. Also the positive charge on the cross resides at far edges of the cross away from the center that's why the electron are not pull back to a line through the center of the cross but more the lines through the edges. the second reason is perhaps a larger contributor